# How to solve error while importing pickle file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to make a traffic sign classification code with following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWaYRyi0TTs) tutorial. I can trained model but when I tried to import pickle file(trined model) to this code ı got an error at **model=pickle.load(hel)**(line 21) how can I solve that ?

Note: I installed tensorflow and pickle.

**Console Messages**

```
2022-03-19 11:53:44.525832: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-03-19 11:53:44.533297: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2022-03-19 11:53:54.072135: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-03-19 11:53:54.084145: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2022-03-19 11:53:54.099108: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2022-03-19 11:53:54.110572: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2022-03-19 11:53:54.120208: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2022-03-19 11:53:54.130490: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_11.dll not found
2022-03-19 11:53:54.140943: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
2022-03-19 11:53:54.150708: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2022-03-19 11:53:54.157514: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1850] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2022-03-19 11:53:54.175013: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTv2I.png)

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pickle
 
frameWidth= 640        
frameHeight = 480
brightness = 180
threshold = 0.90       
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, frameWidth)
cap.set(4, frameHeight)
cap.set(10, brightness)
# IMPORT THE TRANNIED MODEL
hel=open("model_trained.p","rb")  ## rb = READ BYTE
model=pickle.load(hel)
 
def grayscale(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return img
def equalize(img):
    img =cv2.equalizeHist(img)
    return img
def preprocessing(img):
    img = grayscale(img)
    img = equalize(img)
    img = img/255
    return img
def getCalssName(classNo):
    if   classNo == 0: return 'Speed Limit 20 km/h'
    elif classNo == 1: return 'Speed Limit 30 km/h'
    elif classNo == 2: return 'Speed Limit 50 km/h'
    elif classNo == 3: return 'Speed Limit 60 km/h'
    elif classNo == 4: return 'Speed Limit 70 km/h'
    elif classNo == 5: return 'Speed Limit 80 km/h'
    elif classNo == 6: return 'End of Speed Limit 80 km/h'
    elif classNo == 7: return 'Speed Limit 100 km/h'
    elif classNo == 8: return 'Speed Limit 120 km/h'
    elif classNo == 9: return 'No passing'
    elif classNo == 10: return 'No passing for vechiles over 3.5 metric tons'
    elif classNo == 11: return 'Right-of-way at the next intersection'
    elif classNo == 12: return 'Priority road'
    elif classNo == 13: return 'Yield'
    elif classNo == 14: return 'Stop'
    elif classNo == 15: return 'No vechiles'
    elif classNo == 16: return 'Vechiles over 3.5 metric tons prohibited'
    elif classNo == 17: return 'No entry'
    elif classNo == 18: return 'General caution'
    elif classNo == 19: return 'Dangerous curve to the left'
    elif classNo == 20: return 'Dangerous curve to the right'
    elif classNo == 21: return 'Double curve'
    elif classNo == 22: return 'Bumpy road'
    elif classNo == 23: return 'Slippery road'
    elif classNo == 24: return 'Road narrows on the right'
    elif classNo == 25: return 'Road work'
    elif classNo == 26: return 'Traffic signals'
    elif classNo == 27: return 'Pedestrians'
    elif classNo == 28: return 'Children crossing'
    elif classNo == 29: return 'Bicycles crossing'
    elif classNo == 30: return 'Beware of ice/snow'
    elif classNo == 31: return 'Wild animals crossing'
    elif classNo == 32: return 'End of all speed and passing limits'
    elif classNo == 33: return 'Turn right ahead'
    elif classNo == 34: return 'Turn left ahead'
    elif classNo == 35: return 'Ahead only'
    elif classNo == 36: return 'Go straight or right'
    elif classNo == 37: return 'Go straight or left'
    elif classNo == 38: return 'Keep right'
    elif classNo == 39: return 'Keep left'
    elif classNo == 40: return 'Roundabout mandatory'
    elif classNo == 41: return 'End of no passing'
    elif classNo == 42: return 'End of no passing by vechiles over 3.5 metric tons'
 
while True:
    success, imgOrignal = cap.read()
 

    img = np.asarray(imgOrignal)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (32, 32))
    img = preprocessing(img)
    cv2.imshow("Processed Image", img)
    img = img.reshape(1, 32, 32, 1)
    cv2.putText(imgOrignal, "CLASS: " , (20, 35), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(imgOrignal, "PROBABILITY: ", (20, 75), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)



    predictions = model.predict(img)
    classIndex = model.predict_classes(img)
    probabilityValue =np.amax(predictions)
    if probabilityValue > threshold:
    #print(getCalssName(classIndex))
        cv2.putText(imgOrignal,str(classIndex)+" "+str(getCalssName(classIndex)), (120, 35), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.putText(imgOrignal, str(round(probabilityValue*100,2) )+"%", (180, 75), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow("Result", imgOrignal)
 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: Where is the pickle file? Is it in the same location as the script?

Comment: I guess you have verified that the file actually exists in the same folder are your script?

Comment: Yes the pickle file is in the same folder with script.

Comment: @A_normal_guy The image of the error you shared. That is it? Or is there more below?

Comment: The image that I shared shows all the error.

Comment: @A_normal_guy If you do not mind, could you paste the console error messages? Atleast the part pertaining to the pickle file?

Comment: @EchchamaNayak I added.

Comment: @A_normal_guy Thanks. Which operating system is this?

Comment: @EchchamaNayak Windows 10

Comment: @A_normal_guy I am afraid I am on a different system.Somebody else might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install compatible cuda and cudnn versions. Please refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) to know about the build configurations.

OR

If you are working on GPU, the following code suppresses the warning.

```
# It just disables the warning, doesn't take advantage of AVX to run faster
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```

If you're on Unix,try by setting `export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=3`to disable these warnings. Thanks!